# Windows or Linux for FPGA Development?

Tags: linux, windows, fpga

I've been using Linux for FPGA development for years.  I'm at a new place now that uses Windows.  What are some pitfalls that I should be aware of switching from a Linux development environment to a Windows environment?  I use mostly Xilinx ISE and Modelsim.  I have seen some issues setting up environmental variables that work well.  I also don't see the use of Makefiles and some of the benefits that those allow in Windows.  Just wondering others preferences/experiences?

Answer (score 1):

I use windows exclusively for xilinx tools and modelsim.  I used linux tools in the past (7+ years ago) for this, but changed due to tools at work (sounds like you're in a similar boat).  Given that I was in mostly in GUI mode for both there weren't any significant differences.  I know that xilinx provides a shortcut to a terminal window wherein all relevant environment variables are setup for you.  It's found under the accessories folder of the instal directory.  That certainly helps since as you mention there are various environment variable issues that pop up now and then.  Most recently they had an issue where coregen wouldn't load any IP until you set some environment variable.  The xilinx forums are pretty good for that sort of stuff.  Long story short I don't have any pitfalls to share -- it was a pretty seamless transition and not because I did anything to facilitate the transition -- the tools are just that similar.  there are always some head scratchers whenever you update ISE, but that's just ISE for you.  It's possible that I'm totally missing something obvious (it's been a while since I touched the tools on linux and there have been many version changes since then) or that I'm not accurately remembering my linux days with these tools (or the transition to windows), but I don't think you should have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is faster but Windows is easier to install the programmer.